# Laravel CORS headers not shown if user is not auth'ed

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to create an API using Laravel, everything was going well until it came to that point where I have to connect it with Angular on another subdomain. I'm using JWT token-based auth which works fine.

I have created a CORS middleware like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
}
```

Added in Kernel.php and created Route group like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function() {
        Route::get('/test', 'MemberController@test');
    });  
});
```

I'm trying to create a call that checks if user is authenticated and returns that to angular app so the app knows what to show.

I trued like this:

```
public function test()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        echo "logged in";
    } else {
        echo "nuno";
    }
}
```

But that returns the page without CORS headers, but if I remove "else" statement and only leave "if auth" it will return the page with headers.

Also, another problem I have is that JWT returns 400 if the token is invalid or not supplied.

Comment: Without knowing Laravel - I had a very similar problem once using Angular2 (Client) and Go (Server). My problem was, that the Browser did a preflight OPTIONS request *without* sending the JW Token and the server answered with a 400 (or 401). I solved this by allowing preflight OPTION request without a valid token. But as said, I don't know Laravel. Could be something completely different /edit: (And the answer did not contain the CORS headers then!)

Comment: Yeah `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://bridge.impulsealarm.com' is therefore not allowed access.` is there when I try to authenticate via angular factory...

Comment: Guessing that you write something like a REST API, have you tried to configure your Router to always allow OPTIONS preflights without authorization?

Comment: I'm trying to resolve it trough the middleware but somehow middleware is not setting options every time... I mean I can force those settings in index.php as a last resort.

Comment: I had a similar problem and ended up using [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package and it works in all cases except when an unhanded exception is thrown.